# JS-Linking to an anchor inside the document in the onclick() event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem on the following code, imagine the rest is okay (html, head, body etc)
What I want to do is, when you click on one of the buttons the hidden text/images in the section show or hide, the code does that just fine. The problem is I also want it to take you to an anchor in that newly appeared section when you click on the button, and I cant seem to do that.

Here's the code on the HTML

```
<h2 class="especial">TITLE</h2> 
<p class="normal"><input type=image src="images/img_beta/buttonimage1.png" onclick="show_section1();">Section1</p>
<p class="normal"><input type=image src="images/img_beta/buttonimage2.png" onclick="show_section2();">Section2</p>  
<hr>
<div id="Section1" style="display:none">
<a id="Section1_anchor"><h2 class="especial">Sect1TittleHere</h2></a>
    <p class="interior">Blablah this is the content of section1</p> 

</div>
<div id="Section2" style="display:none"> 
<a id="Section2_anchor"><h2 class="especial">Sect2TittleHere</h2></a>
    <p class="interior">Blablah content of section2</p>
    </div>
```

And here's the JS function that controls the onclick event, I have one for each section, but they are all the same.

```
<script language='javascript'>
//Variables
var sect1_guardian=0, sect2_guardian=0, sect3_guardian=0;       
function show_sect1(){
    if (sect1_guardian == 0) {          document.getElementById("Section1").style.display="block";
        sect1_guardian=1;
        //Close the other sections if opened
        document.getElementById("Section2").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("Section3").style.display="none";
        //Reset guardians
        sect2_guardian=0;
        sect3_guardian=0;           
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("Section1").style.display="none";
        sect1_guardian=0;
    }
}
```

Where and how should I add the link to the anchor? If i tried adding it to the button tag and the onclick event. I do something like this

```
<p class="normal"><a href="#Section1_anchor"><input type=image src="images/img_beta/buttonimage1.png" onclick="show_section1();"></a>Section1</p>
```

Because the onclick event is in the image and I don't want the text to be hiperlinked. Clearly I'm loosing something/doing something wrong, probably an humiliating mistake, but I ask for suggestions and corrections.

Answer (score 0):

If it's exactly a copy paste of your code, the onclick handler is called 'show_section1()' and the function is called 'show_sect1()'. Notice sect != section :) .

Should we look further?

Comment: Look further, because its not a direct copy/paste (changed names and stuff) and the showing of hidden divs works just fine, is the anchoring whats giving me trouble :(

Answer (score 0):

You can have the html you proposed and do something like this:

```
window.location = document.getElementById("Section1").parentNode.href;
```

Replace 'Section1' with your particular section.

Comment: I put it on my JS function and it does not work, firebug says:TypeError: document.getElementById(...).getParent is not a function. I guess I'm still doing something wrong... >_<

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I found a solution, it was far easier and probably nobody said it because I was presenting the problem in the wrong way, but perhaps this will help somebody.

I wanted to make the button take you to an anchor in the document, right?

The code above worked well, you clicked on the button and it showed hidden text, or hide it.

Now, adding the following to the button code, it does the anchor thingy also.

```
<p class="normal"><a href="#Section1"><input type=image src="images/img_beta/buttonimage1.png" onclick="show_section1();"></a>Section1</p>
```

I just added a  tag to link the button, and used the HTML id (which I already used for the JS) to function as an anchor. I hope to have explained it clearly, and that it helps somebody!

Key was, use the html id as an anchor